# How to change the borders and background styles (color, views...) of my CDEditor manually?

Tags: javascript, html, css, ckeditor

I manage a website, and I use CDEditor for some reasons. I want to adapt the design of CDEditor to the website design, and for that reason, I downloaded CDEditor and tried to edit some sources files.

I tried for instance to edit contents.css, but it only helped me to alter the text color and the font-size, but not the background color or border color that I also wanted.

I also tried to edit the border (or background) properties in .../ckeditor/skins/editor.css, but nothing happened.

Now I don't know what to do, 
please help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for your views, I just got a solution to the problem by reading this tutorial :

http://o7planning.org/web/fe/default/en/document/640241/ckeditor-tutorial

It has a lot of great tips and tricks to customize ckeditors.
For example, to change background color, we can use this :

```js
CKEDITOR.replace( 'textarea_id', {
    uiColor: '#14B8C4'
});
```